# ExtJS, Sencha Build Tools and a website that requires authentication

Tags: extjs4, extjs, extjs4.1

Is there any way a user can submit the authentication data (username&password) to the following Sencha Build Tools command:

```
sencha create jsb -a https://localhost:8443/my/site -p app.jsb3
```

Found [this](http://blog.lansdowntech.com/2012/02/creating-an-extjs-production-build-with-sencha-sdk-tools/) useful; it states:

> There doesn’t seem to be anyway to specify any necessary
>   username/password to Sencha SDK tools, so you’ll need to run against a
>   local webserver instance that doesn’t require HTTP authentication.

However I don't have the luxury of running without an authenticated user (would break the server-side).

What can be done? Any features added/improved in recent versions?

Comment: What do you mean `would break the server-side`? I have ExtJs application which require ASP.NET authentication to get actual data, but when you build minified version Sencha SDK will not request any data from the server - it basically will go through list of .js files, that's it.

Comment: @sha Since it's Tomcat6 form-based auth, I cannot get to the real page without logging in. And removing the form-based auth would break the server-side as the latter needs a logged in user to operate. Can work on "breaking" it; i.e. make it work without a logged in user, but only as last resort. Cheers.

Comment: Are you saying you have several html files and app.js is not on the first of them?

Comment: @sha `app.js` is in the file (the only one) after successfully logging in.

Comment: I still don't understand... :) Can you post your index.html file please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I did it. I would love to hear if anyone has a better suggestion.

1. Create a test web page with `Ext.require` root level references. This need not have any server side coding. Remember to enable dynamic loading by `Ext.Loader.setConfig( {enabled: true...})`
2. Make it accessible without authentication.
3. Open the page in Firefox and use Firebug's Net panel verify all of your js files are loaded.
4. Now you can use this page URL with Sencha tools.

Comment: What would "root level references" be? Do you use [`Ext.Loader.history`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Loader-property-history) to determine them?

Comment: Say classA requires classB and classB requires classC. Then you add classA to Ext.require. Is your problem still unresolved?